# Will my images be packaged in the apk even if they are not used?

Tags: android

I have a bunch of country flags in my drawable folders for a total of about 5mb. I was wondering if all the images will be packaged in the apk or only the one I reference to in the code.

If all the image get packaged, is there a way to only package those that I use in my code? (by using r.drawable.myimage)?

Thank you

Comment: Yes all the resources will be packaged..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all resources will be included in your APK even if they are not used.

If you use Gradle build system you can enable `shrinkResources`:

> The Gradle build system for Android supports "resource shrinking": the
>   automatic removal of resources that are unused, at build time, in the
>   packaged app. In addition to removing resources in your project that
>   are not actually needed at runtime, this also removes resources from
>   libraries you are depending on if they are not actually needed by your
>   application.

Reference
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: shrinkResources is exactly what I need, Thank you